# Reading event logs from Application and services logs using c# | PrintServices

Tags: c#, events, event-viewer

Is there any way to fetch 'Application and Services logs' from event viewer by using c#? 
I could able to read the logs from windows logs but not from application and services logs. Exactly what i require is to read the log named 'Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational'

Please suggest...!

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string logType = "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational";
string query = "*[System/EventID=307]";

var elQuery = new 
    EventLogQuery(logType, PathType.LogName, query);
var elReader = new EventLogReader(elQuery);

for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent(); eventInstance != null; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EventLog` class with your custom log name. Read at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9hdxtte(v=vs.90).aspx) for more.